# Javascript Canvas Ignoring .beginPath() affecting .fillStyle()

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fill

The program includes a rectangle with a given color based on a button clicked in the HTML passing the color into the method. There is also another text field and button to add text to this rectangle but the color of the text isn't staying independent from the rectangle color. This means the rectangle always gets set to whatever color the text is. What I am trying to do is have the color of the bag selectable and then have the text on the bag selectable whilst keeping the color of the bag the same. I thought the `context.beginPath()` is supposed to allow these to be seperate but it doesnt seem to be doing that. Any help on what I should be doing instead?

JavaScript File

```
function drawCanvas(color) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var logoText = document.getElementById("logoText").value;


    //Draws the bag and sets the color
    context.beginPath()
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.fillRect(10,30,200,200);

    //Draws the border outline of the bag
    context.beginPath();
    context.lineWidth = "2";
    context.rect(10,30,200,200);
    context.stroke()

    //Draws the handle
    context.beginPath();
    context.lineWidth = "2";
    context.rect(85,5,50,25);
    context.stroke();

    context.save();
    context.restore();

    context.beginPath();
    context.font = "24px Times";
    context.fillStyle = "black";
    context.textAlign = "center";
    context.fillText(logoText, canvas.width/2, canvas.width/2);

}
window.onload = drawCanvas;
```

HTML File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang = "en">

    <head>

        <title>mas00266 - Plastic Bag Inc. - Order Page</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "stylesheet.css" />
        <script type = "text/javascript" src = "script.js"></script>
        <meta charset = "UTF-8">    

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class = "flex-container">
            <div class = "box">
                <h1 id = "left"> The Bag Company </h1>
            </div>
            <div class = "box">
                <h3 style = "text-align: right; padding: 15px"> Welcome to our orders page! </h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <nav>

            <ul class = "navStyle">
                <li><a href = "Homepage.html">Home</a></li>
                <li  class = "active"><a href = "#">Order</a></li>
                <li><a href = "#">Contact</a></li>
                <li><a href = "#">Login</a></li>
            </ul>

        </nav>

            <br>
            <br>
            <canvas id = "myCanvas" width = "220" height = "240"></canvas>
            <br>
            <br>
            <h4>Choose your bag color:</h4>
            <button type = "button" onclick = "drawCanvas('black')">Black</button>
            <button type = "button" onclick = "drawCanvas('white')">White</button>
            <button type = "button" onclick = "drawCanvas('red')">Red</button>
            <button type = "button" onclick = "drawCanvas('blue')">Blue</button>
            <button type = "button" onclick = "drawCanvas('green')">Green</button>
            <br>
            <h4>Enter text on the bag:</h4>
            <input id = "logoText" type = "text" name = "textInputField" size = "12">
            <button type = "button" onclick = "drawCanvas()">Add Text</button>



    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: So I realise every time I call the drawCanvas method throught the  Add Text button the color is not being remembered. I can't however figure out how I would get around this. I have tried calling through another method to hold the chosen color but that hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MDN has this to say on [`.beginPath()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/beginPath), [`.save()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/save), and [`.restore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/restore):

> The **CanvasRenderingContext2D.beginPath()** method of the Canvas 2D API starts a new path by emptying the list of sub-paths. Call this method when you want to create a new path.

> The **CanvasRenderingContext2D.save()** method of the Canvas 2D API saves the entire state of the canvas by pushing the current state onto a stack.

> The **CanvasRenderingContext2D.restore()** method of the Canvas 2D API restores the most recently saved canvas state by popping the top entry in the drawing state stack. If there is no saved state, this method does nothing.

As you can see, `.beginPath()` doesn't have anything to do with drawing context other than setting up for a new path. Instead, you would use `.save()` to create a kind of save point for the current context (which includes all the current drawing parameters such colors, patterns, and transforms), make and use your changes to that context, then use `.restore()` to recover from those changes by reverting to the previous save point.

Based on that, and your goal, your code should look something like:

```
function drawCanvas(color) {
    // onload doesn't call this with an argument so make sure we have a default
    color = color || "blue";

    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var logoText = document.getElementById("logoText").value;

    //Set various base styles in our drawing context
    context.fillStyle = "black";
    context.font = "24px Times";
    context.textAlign = "center";
    context.lineWidth = "2";

    //Draws the bag and sets the color
    context.save(); // save current drawing context state to the stack
    context.fillStyle = color;
    context.fillRect(10,30,200,200);
    content.restore(); // recover to previous saved state and remove it from the stack

    //Draws the border outline of the bag
    context.rect(10,30,200,200);
    context.stroke()

    //Draws the handle
    context.rect(85,5,50,25);
    context.stroke();

    context.fillText(logoText, canvas.width/2, canvas.width/2);
}
window.onload = drawCanvas;
```